# Permission to create VIEW for table with SELECT right

Tags: oracle, view, permissions

I'm granted SELECT on table NOTMYSCHEMA.XYZ but Oracle does not allow me to create VIEW that includes this table! What's the purpose of this ban? I assume if I can see the table content then I should be allowed to make a view showing this table content by default.

Comment: If you are in the same schema, you are still missing `execute` permission to `create` the view.

Comment: No, the table is from another schema.

Comment: Do you have execute permission on the schema where u r trying to create view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Privileges Required to Create Views

To create a view, you must meet the following requirements:

You must have been granted the CREATE VIEW (to create a view in your schema) or CREATE ANY VIEW (to create a view in another user's schema) system privilege, either explicitly or through a role.

You must have been **explicitly** granted the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE object privileges on **all base objects underlying the view** or the SELECT ANY TABLE, INSERT ANY TABLE, UPDATE ANY TABLE, or DELETE ANY TABLE system privileges. You may not have obtained these privileges through roles.

Additionally, in order to grant other users access to your view, you must have received object privilege(s) to the base objects with the GRANT OPTION option or appropriate system privileges with the ADMIN OPTION option. If you have not, grantees cannot access your view."

Comment: Of course that I do have the permission for creating view. The problem is that I can't create a view for table that I have the SELECT permission. One permission is to see table and another permission is for creating view for that table. My question is what's the reason for this?

Comment: then you need to add "with read only" keyword to end of script. as you know with default options simple view is a updateable.

Comment: you can look [this article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_insifficient_privileges_create_view_grant.htm) from Burleson Consulting

Comment: Thanks, I confirmed your response as answer to my question, but this article explains that I need explicit SELECT permission on underlaying table (not inplicit through role allowing me to see this table). This explains what to do in order to be able to create view, but again, this does not explain why this works that way. If I can see the table content (through role) why I'm not allowed to create view and see it through the view.